# How can i get a tweet for a specific url?

Tags: android, twitter, capture

I want some resource which can lead me to capture tweets for only a specific links.
Suppose i will capture all tweets which contain a link http://aaa.com
how can i do it ?
thanks

Comment: I forget to include it will use a android

Comment: yes, i added for you answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about Twitter API [here](https://dev.twitter.com/), but better library is [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html).

Here you have code samples to :

- add new tweet :

  ```
  Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
  Status status = twitter.updateStatus(latestStatus);
  System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
  ```
- geting timeline :

  ```
     Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
     List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
    System.out.println("Showing home timeline.");
     for (Status status : statuses) {
        System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" +
                         status.getText());
  }
  ```
- Log in Twitter using OAuth (code for Java, edit this):

  ```
  Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
  twitter.setOAuthConsumer("[consumer key]", "[consumer secret]");
  RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
  AccessToken accessToken = null;
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  while (null == accessToken) {
    System.out.println("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
    System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
    System.out.print("Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:");
    String pin = br.readLine();
    try{
       if(pin.length() > 0){
         accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
       }else{
         accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
       }
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
      if(401 == te.getStatusCode()){
        System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
      }else{
        te.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
  //persist to the accessToken for future reference.
  storeAccessToken(twitter.verifyCredentials().getId() , accessToken);
  Status status = twitter.updateStatus(args[0]);
  System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
  System.exit(0);
  ```

  }

  private static void storeAccessToken(int useId, AccessToken accessToken){
         //store accessToken.getToken()
         //store accessToken.getTokenSecret()

  - getting tweets :

    ```
    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j yusukey");
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    for (Status status : result.getStatuses()) {
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
    }
    ```

I hope I helped.

Source : http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the Twitter API. https://dev.twitter.com/

As it is, this question is a bit too open-ended to be answered easily. In essence, you're going to be using the API to pull a given tweet, then using some of your own code to parse for the URL you want to check, and then finally doing something with the URL or tweet.

Please do a bit of research and come back with a more specific question.